# How can I use numpy.mean() on ndarray with a condition?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to filter values of an ndarray and at the same time take the mean with regards to a certain axis?
Here is MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import random

arr = np.ndarray((10, 5))

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(5):
        arr[i, j] = random.randint(0, 5)

mean = arr[arr < 0.7].mean(axis = 0)
```

This is not working as `arr[arr < 0.7]` is the flattes the array.

Any other idea?

Comment: If you say not working, what is your expected result?

Comment: This calculates the global mean value as `arr[condition]` returns a flattened array. I expect to get a list of 5 mean values.

Comment: Then Divakar's answer should work for you. Alternatively you could replace the values you don't want with NaN and use `np.nanmean`: 1. `arr[arr<0.7] = np.nan` 2. `mean=np.nanmean(arr, axis=0)` but I think the other solution is faster and cleaner (yet maybe slightly less readable).

Comment: Note your loop can be replaced with `arr = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(10, 5))`

Comment: `arr[arr<0.7] = np.nan` will only work if `arr.dtype` is a floating-point type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use the mask of valid ones set by the comparison against the given threshold, get the sum of elements along `axis=0` and divide those by the number of valid ones participating in the summations to get the desired output of `average` values from the valid ones.

Thus, the implementation would be something like this -

```
mask = arr < thresh
out = np.einsum('ij,ij->j',arr,mask)/mask.sum(axis = 0)
```

Sample step-by-step run -

```
In [49]: arr
Out[49]: 
array([[ 4.,  3.,  2.,  5.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  5.,  1.,  4.],
       [ 2.,  5.,  1.,  2.,  4.],
       [ 0.,  4.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  3.,  3.,  0.],
       [ 5.,  0.,  0.,  4.,  1.],
       [ 4.,  2.,  0.,  5.,  3.],
       [ 5.,  0.,  0.,  5.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  2.,  1.]])

In [50]: thresh = 4

In [51]: mask = arr < thresh

In [52]: mask
Out[52]: 
array([[False,  True,  True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [53]: np.einsum('ij,ij->j',arr,mask)
Out[53]: array([  5.,  10.,   6.,   9.,   8.])

In [54]: np.einsum('ij,ij->j',arr,mask)/mask.sum(axis = 0)
Out[54]: array([ 1.        ,  1.42857143,  0.66666667,  1.5       ,  1.        ])
```

Talking of "readability", alternatively, we can use simple elementwise multiplication and summing, like so -

```
out = (arr*mask).sum(axis = 0)/mask.sum(axis = 0)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works pretty fine. I didn't know about einsum. [Documentation einsum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)

Comment: @Schneemannbruzzler Yes! Always a good practice to follow docs and try to understand the codes and thus escape the "readability" talk!

Answer (score 1):

You could use masked arrays here:

```
ok_mask = arr < 0.7
np.ma.masked_where(~ok_mask, arr).mean(axis=0)
```

If an entire slice along the 0 axis is excluded, then this will return `np.masked` in that entry

Comment: Think its worth mentioning in the post that comparison operator was reversed to avoid any confusion. Also, I guess we need to use `>=` there, to be opposite of `<`.